# react select options are not getting displayed properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select, react-dom

I am building an application using react, so I was using `react-select` library for select elements. I have followed the documentation and used it, but unfortunately the options are displaying in blue color, whereas if we see in the tutorial they are transparent, only the selected item highlights.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Gv6.png)

Here's the codesandbox url : https://codesandbox.io/s/pwkl54q2jj

What workarounds I have tried:

1. Downgrading react and react-dom versions.
2. Taking out the component from `CategoryForm` component to `App` component where the state lies. Didn't work
3. Tried out the code given in the documentation : https://codesandbox.io/s/vm8x1jmm00?module=/example.js in my setup by creating a new component and rendering it.
4. Removing all the divs and abstracted select out of them.

Nothing works... Anyone help out here???

I hope I have provided all the info that's needed. Please comment if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you telll me in which file you have the dropdown?

Comment: in category.js file

Comment: basically I am using uplifting there, my state is in `App` component, from there I am lifting up to `TransactionForm` and from there to `CategoryForm`

Comment: Not sure what's causing it, but it seems the interaction classes are not being applied to the elements inside the select menu. In the working example, the class on each item is changing based on hover / active state, but it is not changing in your example.

Comment: @DanielBernardi yes, I too observed that... I scratched my head for longtime, then came here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Swap the `name` key for `value` in your categories array and it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rm7pnv2xpq

Comment: Thanks... How stupid I am... I overlooked it... my bad... banging my head... thank you :)

Comment: One thing, I am getting this error `A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type hidden to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).`, do you know how to resolve it??? I am using onChange handler is it because of it may be ??

Comment: Got that, have to remove `value` prop from select